# Preserving recursive directory structure in zips with Java 8

Tags: recursion, java-8, zip

I have the following directory on my laptop:

```
/tmp/
    myapp/
        assets/
            config.yml
            models/
                troll.ply
                tree.ply
            textures/
                troll-skin.png
                tree-skin.png
```

I would like to zip `/tmp/myapp/assets` (and all its recursive contents) up into a ZIP named `assets.zip`, such that, when I unzip it (via `unzip assets.zip`), it preserves the directory structure under the `assets` folder. Hence, when unzipped, it would show `config.yml` in the "root" of the ZIP, and 2 directories inside the ZIP (`models` and `textures`). The rest of the files would be inside these respective subdirectories, etc.

When I run this code:

```
File sourceDir = new File("/tmp/myapp/assets");
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/myuser/archives/assets.zip"));

File[] contents = sourceDir.listFiles();
for(File file : contents) {
    zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.name));
    InputStream isteam = new FileInputStream(file);

    Files.copy(isteam, zip);
    zip.closeEntry();
    isteam.close();
}

zip.close();
```

The code correctly creates a ZIP at `/Users/myuser/archives/assets.zip`.

**However**, when I unzip it (`unzip /Users/myuser/archives/assets.zip`) and then run `ls -al /Users/myuser/archives`, my output is:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  1754083733  492 Dec 30 14:14 assets.zip
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  1754083733   10 Dec 30 14:14 config.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  1754083733    7 Dec 30 14:14 models
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser  1754083733    9 Dec 30 14:14 textures
```

So both `models` and `textures` are being treated like **files** (not as directories). Furthermore, when I take a peek at the contents of the "`models` file", it appears that the *contents* of `troll.ply` and `tree.ply` have been concatenated inside of it, and ditto for the "`tree` file" with the 2 PNGs.

**How can I tweak this so that directory structure (no matter how deep/nested) is always preserved in the resultant ZIP?**

Comment: There is no recursion in your code…

Answer (score 1):

you can probably use the recursive method call to preserve the sub directories structure:

```
 private static void addDir(File sourceDir, ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException {
    File[] contents = sourceDir.listFiles();
    for(File file : contents) {
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            addDir(file, zip);
        } else {
            zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getAbsolutePath().replace("/tmp/myapp/","")));
            System.out.println("file name " + file.getAbsolutePath().replace("/tmp/myapp/",""));
            Path rn_demo = Paths.get(String.valueOf(file));
            Files.copy(rn_demo, zip);
        }
    }
    zip.closeEntry();
}
```

and you call in main method as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File sourceDir = new File("/tmp/myapp/assets");
    ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/myuser/archives/assets.zip"));
    addDir(sourceDir, zip);
    zip.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sasi (+1) your solution **appears** to work at runtime, but when I go to unzip the ZIP file from the command-line, I get the following error: `Archive:  assets.zip End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of assets.zip or assets.zip.zip, and cannot find assets.zip.ZIP, period...`

Comment: I noticed you are not closing ZIP entries anywhere (`zip.closeEntry()`), could that be the problem?

Comment: @smeeb: how are you unzipping the file? i haven't got any problem. can you type file "yourfilename" from your cmd line, (this will give type of the file if it OSX or *inux systems)

Comment: i do closing zip entry, see the first snippet

Answer (score 0):

Zipping through Java Zip seems to work differently on different OS's. I had the issue that it was working fine on Windows 7. But on Linux (RHEL6) the files were before the folders. This caused tests to fail.

A way to solve it is to sort the files and folders. folders first and then files. So the..

```
File[] contents = sourceDir.listFiles();
```

...File array should be sorted via path. Create a List<> from the Files and sort.

```
Collections.sort(newFiles, (a, b) ->
            b.getAbsolutePath().compareTo(a.getAbsolutePath())
    );
```

Note, I created an InputFile object to store the absolute path of the file.